# Saving image location to MySQL DB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Been exhausting myself again trying to see what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to upload a photo to my page and save its location to the mysql using prepared statements.  My code is as follows

```
<?php

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session
require("common.php");

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the email is logged in or not
if(empty($_SESSION['email']))
{
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page.
    header("Location: ../index.html");
    die("Redirecting to FrontPage");
}

$email = $_SESSION['email']['email'];

//Profile Image upload script
if(isset($_FILES['profilepic']))
{
    if((($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || ($_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif")) && ($_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576)) 
    {
        $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
        mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");

        if(file_exists("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]."Already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"], "userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);

            $profile_pic_name = $_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];

            $queryProfilePic = "UPDATE db SET profilePic=:profile_Pic WHERE email = :email";

            $query_params = array(':profile_Pic' => $rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name,':email' => $email);

            $stmt = $db->prepare($queryProfilePic);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

            //header("Location: profile.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }   
}

?>
```

The image is uploaded to the randomly generated folder on the server however when I try to save the location of the file to the db I get a big goose egg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot divide these values:

```
$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name
```

I assume you want to concatenate them:

```
$rand_dir_name . '/' . $profile_pic_name
```

or you can use

```
"$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name"
```